# Copy data from excel sheet to another using macro

Tags: excel

I have a sheet Rolling Plan in copy.xls worksheet.I want to copy it to Book1.xls worksheet in Sheet NO1 in Range A1:H6

**The macro in Book.xls**

```
  Sub CopytoPS()
   Dim sfil As String
   Dim owbk As Workbook
   Dim sPath As String

   sPath = "C:\Users\Nirmala\Desktop\website" 'Change the file path for your purposes
   sfil = Dir(sPath & "copy.xls")

   Range("B6:H6").Copy
   Set owbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sfil)
   owbk.Sheets("RollinPlan").Range("B6:H6").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).
   PasteSpecial  xlPasteValues
    owbk.Close True 'Save opened workbook and close
    sfil = Dir
```

End Sub

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? It does not copy? It copies to the incorrect range?

Comment: It is not copying and error is subscript out of range error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the following:

1) Open `copy.xls` and copy data in range `B6:H6`

2) Pastes the data into workbook `Book1` in range `A1:H6` on sheet `NO1`

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim filePath As String, wb As Workbook

    filePath = "C:\Users\Nirmala\Desktop\website" 'Change the file path for your purposes
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath & "\" & "copy.xls")

    wb.Worksheets("Rolling Plan").Range("B6:H6").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NO1").Range("A1:H6")
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Note that I am not quite sure why the data range you are copying to (i.e. `A1:H6`) is much larger than the actual copied range (i.e. `B6:H6`).

Comment: i have changed A1:H6 to B5:H5 it is working fine.I want to actually copy data from MPP to excel.How will I do that

Comment: @prerna - Great stuff! Can I ask you to accept the answer if you are happy? That way other users who have a similar issue can have confidence in the answer provided.

Comment: yes but I have a issue regarding copying MPP file to excel.will this code work for MPP.Do u have any idea

Comment: If `MPP` is Microsoft Project File then I have never worked with that before. Why not try and see what happens?

Comment: @prerna - having not worked with MPP I am not sure I can help you any further. Maybe take this question down and re-ask with specific reference to MPP in the title?